# Lost NAS on Raspberry Pi After Bridged Connection

Tags: raspberry-pi3, nas, bridge

I'm fairly new to the Raspberry Pi.  Running Raspian-Jessie.  The first thing I did was set it up as a Plex Server using my NAS as the file system.  This has been working great for me.

The next thing I did was bridge the wifi to the ethernet port so we could connect a Magic Jack directly to the Pi instead of plugging it into our router (which is not in a spot that makes sense for us to have a phone).  The Magic Jack is working great, but since bridging the wifi to the ethernet port, I seem to have lost my ability to connect to the NAS.  I verified on the fstab file that the settings are the same.  I'm also able to ping the NAS, but can't seem to mount.  I have a backup copy of the SD card from before I made the bridge changes, and verified I can connect to the NAS with that.

Anybody have any idea how I can go about fixing this?  I'll be happy to post any files that might help, but I'm not sure what to throw up here, so if need be, ask away!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently at the exact same time I created my bridge, something updated with the CIFS settings.  I now have to specify the version on the fstab file, but it's all back up now.